# Cannot create property "appState" on number "200" using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get AngularJS to hide a login form once it has been answered, 
and replace it by the data sent by the server (for the moment a local JSON).

This is my controller:

```
app.controller("testController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    var eventList = this,
        dataReceived;

    eventList.events = [];


    $scope.submitLogin = function ($scope, http) {

        var response = $http.get("../json/Login.json");
        response.success(function (data, $scope) {
            $scope.appState = {};
            $scope.appState.bool = false;
            if (data.success) {
                eventList.events = data.eventHead;
                $scope.appState.bool = true;

            } else {
                window.alert(data.ErroMsg);
            }
        });
        response.error(function (data) {
            window.alert("Error");
        });
    };
}]);
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<div class="login-page" ng-hide="appState.bool">
        <div class="form">
            <img src="images/magnum.jpg" class="spacerSpe">
            <form class="login-form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Matricule" />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Annee de Naissance" />
                <button ng-click="submitLogin()" >Log In</button>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="appState.bool" align="center">...</div>
```

So the login page should hide once the submit button is pressed (for the moment there is no actual auth, it just works if you press the button) but for some reason i get this error message and angular doesn't acknowledge that my 
`$scope.appState.bool` has changed.

The exact message is

> ErrorNotification.js:125 ConsoleAgent: TypeError: Cannot create property 'appState' on number '200'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to sshow and Rob Louie for pointing out my horrible $htttp.get syntax, and for noticing that my scope definition was misplaced; ill leave the final controller code here in case it helps someone

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    var eventList = this;
    eventList.events = [];

  $scope.submitLogin = function () {
    $scope.appState = {};
    $scope.appState.bool = false ;

    var promise = $http.get('../json/Login.json');
    promise.then(function (response) {
        $scope.appState.bool = true;

    }, function (error) {
      window.alert('Error' + error);
    });
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation for $http: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Your syntax is wrong and should be updated, but I think the main problem is that you are creating a new local variable named $scope inside your "success" callback and setting your variables there.  You need to set them on the regular $scope variable.

Comment: First thank you for your answer. I corrected my code according to the doc, but when i declare $scope.appState on the regular scope variable, i get another error  angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot set property 'appState' of undefined

Comment: Can you post your updated code or make a jsfiddle or something that shows what it looks like now?

Comment: it works now i posted the updated controller in the answers thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, looks much better :)

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you are calling on `submitLogin` without any parameters.

```
<button ng-click="submitLogin()" >Log In</button>
```

However, your function definition for `submitLogin()` expects two parameters.

```
$scope.submitLogin = function ($scope, http) { [...]
```

both of which are already defined in the scope on line 1.

```
app.controller("testController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
```

Using `.success()` and `.error()` on promises is deprecated in favor of the standard `.then(success, error)` pattern. So, `$http.get()` returns a promise with `response` as data.

More likely you should be doing something like this:

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.submitLogin = function () {
    var promise = $http.get('../json/Login.json');
    promise.then(function (response) {
      window.alert('Response is 200');
    }, function (error) {
      window.alert('Error' + error);
    });
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It's a syntax error, you're missing `$` in the http in the `$scope.submitLogin = function ($scope, http) { ... }`